# Correcting or Adjusting Binomial Test for Temporal Autocorrelation

Tags: binomial-distribution, autocorrelation

Is there a relatively standard approach for adjusting or accounting for autocorrelation when conducting the large-sample approximation version of the binomial test? I have an equally-spaced timeseries dataset of n=355 observations that are autocorrelated. Perhaps an effective sample size adjustment?

Thank you -

Comment: Could you describe in a little more detail what you mean by "the binomial test"?  Exactly what is your hypothesis, what is the nature of the data (Bernoulli responses or not?), and what statistic would you use?

Comment: More specifically, the timeseries data are radiation rates. The hypothesis I want to test is if more than 5% of the dataset exceed a specific radiation rate. The test I had in mind is the large-sample test for population proportion. The timeseries are autocorrelated.

Comment: Let's begin by clarifying the test.  A simple calculation will establish whether or not more than 5% of the *dataset* exceeded a specific rate.  I doubt that's your interest.  You likely have some model of radiation and you want to know whether the true radiation exceeded a threshold more than 5% of the time.  Right?  If so, any additional information you might have about the measurement system and your expectations concerning the temporal variation of the radiation can be helpful.

Comment: My apologies for not responding to this sooner. I do not have a model, per se, of radiation or radiation rates. Rather, I would like to conduct a hypothesis test on the dataset to test if more than 5% of the dataset is greater than a threshold at a specified significance level. It is my understanding the binomial test assumes independent data